# Bring an object to the front, while keeping same child indexes on the parent.  AS3/FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

When we click on an image it should come in front as the selected image, but I dont want to change the index value of that image

```
canvas1.setChilIndex(Image(event.target), numChildern-1)
```

The above line is changing the index value of the selected image and setting it to maximum-1 (for ex: 5-1 = 4 as index value). I Need alternate for above line that keeps the same index for the image.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you can't bring the image to the front, but don't want to change the index.

Comment: yes @michael, i mean the same. Do you have any suggestion for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is in your click handler store the index of the item clicked, then on the next click (or whenever you want), send the item back to its previous index:

```
var previousImg:Image;
var previousIndex:int;

function selectImage(img:Image):void {
    deselectImage(); //if there is already a selected image, put it back before moving this new one to the top

    previousImg = img;    
    previousIndex = canvas1.getChildIndex(img);
    canvas1.addChild(img); //brings it to the front
}

function deselectImage():void {
    if(previousImg){
        canvas1.setChildIndex(previousImage, previousIndex);
        previousImg = null;  //null the var in case you call this method manually
    }
}
```

so in your click handler, do this instead of the line you have in your question:

```
selectImage(Image(event.target));
```

With this method, anytime you call `selectImage`, it will put the last click one back where it belongs. You could also call `deselectImage` manually if you so desired.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, because in flash child index is the only criterion of drawing order.

If you want to hold the order of adding images, you can store images, for example, in array, then every next item will have index in order of adding.

Answer (score 0):

When I see your question, I have the same ideas that LondonDrugs and Roman suggested above.  However, your question is quite simple, so the answer is not possible.

The situation is quite complicated if I don't know the flow of the application.

For example, if you will add image to your canvas at the run time after you selected an image then which order of index you would like to roll back?

My suggestion:
You can set a cut point that you want to keep the order of index, then use a loop to find the index of all the image and keep it in an array.  When the user finished playing, roll the index back to the cut point.